# Can iOS GCM coexist with native Apple pushes?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I want to add GCM 3.0 for iOS to my app for some specific communication between my client and server, but my app already uses regular Apple Push messages for other things, and I want to keep it that way (i.e. I don't want to switch everything over to GCM).

I understand that GCM for iOS sends downstream messages through APNS when the app is in the background. My question is, will this interfere with my existing uses of Apple Push messages? For example, maybe GCM's push message will have a badge of zero and that removes my app's badge that was set by my regular pushes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will have both your own APNS provider and GCM sending notifications to APNS, they will interfere with each other, but not in the way you expect. The problem would be with receiving feedback from APNS: GCM will receive a part of feedback periodically without knowing what feedback your own provider received, and vice versa, which may cause bad behavior as it seems from APNS perspective and lead to APNS connection drops.

As for using GCM without APNS, apparently GCM doesn't encourage that.

Comment: so is there a way to use GCM without it eating my APNS feedback?

Comment: @user102008 I don't think so